# Getting parsing error with the following case statement in Cognos

Tags: sql, case, cognos

```
case when ([JOB_CLASS]='T') then [SQL2].[ESTJOBDURATION]/60
     else 0
end
```

This is the definition i have for a data item. The data item is using aggregate total function in Cognos property pane.
I am trying to total the estimated job duration in hours when job class is equal to T.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Your syntax is good.  Just verified in a simple test.

Comment: Just found out I missed the "then" keyword in the case statement of another data item's definition. It is really strange that clicking on the validation button would return parsing errors for every data item definition, though only one of the them is incorrect. Anyway thanks for your help guys.